# Get all the missing dates in a sequence of dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, paraccel

I am trying to get all the missing dates in a sequence of dates which are in an ascending order. How can I do it using a simple sql without using any functions or udfs.

```
Input :-

2016-09-01
2016-09-02
2016-09-05
2016-09-10
```

Output :-

```
2016-09-03
2016-09-04
2016-09-06
2016-09-07
2016-09-08
2016-09-09
```

What I have tried?

```
  select start, stop 
    from
       (
          select m.x + 1 as start,
                 (select min(x) - 1 from X as x where x.x > m.x) as stop
            from X as m
           left outer join X as r
              on m.x = r.x - 1
           where r.x is null
        ) as x
  where stop is not null;
```

Comment: it would help if you tag the dbms being used and also show your attempt.

Comment: I am trying to solve it using integers and then jump onto dates.

Comment: does your db support recursive common table expressions?

Comment: Yes CTEs are supported

Comment: Does not look like missing dates to me

Comment: I need all the missing dates which are not present in the input date sequence

Comment: Well 2016-09-01 is in that sequence

Comment: changed the output

Comment: I prepared a sql which will generate ranges of the missing numbers but stuck with building the missing numbers from the above ranges.

Comment: Is anyone out there to help me on this problem?

Answer (score -1):

1. create a new table and insert 365 rows numbered 1-365 
   (alternately use a table that already has more than 365 rows and use rownum or similar construct to get unique integers)
2. Convert your dates to integers (in Oracle use something like `TO_CHAR( mydate, 'ddd' )`)
3. join these two list together in your query to find the appropriate set (overlap, missing etc.)
4. convert back to dates

Comment: I am using amazon redshift

Comment: @Teja I don't understand Amazon Redshift supports cte's.

Comment: Amazon Redshift doesnt support recursive ctes. Check this link. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html

Comment: This answer doesnt help me Randy :(

Comment: ok - sorry - this is the pattern you use to avoid CTE - you need another table with all the dates in it to compare to - the integers are the best option.